# pytest can't find pytest.fixture_request

Tags: python, pytest

I am attempting to utilize the [alternative approach](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/proposals/parametrize_with_fixtures.html#alternative-approach) listed in the PyTest documentation here. My `parametrize` decorator call looks like this

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("val1, params, result", [
    ('a string', pytest.fixture_request('valid_type'), 150)

])
```

However, when I run `pytest` I get the following error:

```
test_get_responses.py:102: in <module>
    ('a string', pytest.fixture_request('valid_type'), 150)
E   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fixture_request'
```

The `valid_type` fixture does exist.

I am running pytest version 3.2.0

How can I solve this problem, so that I can utilize the 'alternative approach' listed in the documentation above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The described approach is only a proposal that has not been implemented yet (as you can see in this discussion: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349#issuecomment-286451346). As a workaround, you can use the package `pytest-lazy-fixture` (can be installed with `pip`): instead of `pytest.fixture_request('fixture_name')` just use `pytest.lazy_fixture('fixture_name')`.